# How to make ternary statements in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a school project and encountered this kind of scenario after ExecuteNonQuery Sqlcommand

```
MsgBox(c.ExecuteNonQuery > 0, "Update Success! Acctid " & acctid.Text, "Update Failed!")
```

As you can see, I applied a ternary statement in the msgbox with the condition of the command execution good. I tested it and it was executed but the program crashed due to > "Update Success! Acctid 1"(acctid.text already concatenated) error. String to integer, casting exception
Conversion from string "Update Success! Acctid 1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Why is that? clearly the return must be string and nothing in that statement should be initiating a conversion from string to integer. It was the in other way in the first place, which is a valid concatenation from two strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I applied a ternary statement in the msgbox"*. Um, no you didn't.  You just supplied three arguments to `MsgBox` with no regard for what the function is expecting. The ternary operator in VB is `If` and there's no `If` in your code. If you want to use a ternary operator then you need to use one:

```
MsgBox(If(c.ExecuteNonQuery > 0, "Update Success! Acctid " & acctid.Text, "Update Failed!"))
```